# How to use spaces in the URL path in mod_alias’ Redirect directive?

Tags: spaces, mod-alias

Following on from [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776942/trouble-redirecting-all-pages-in-a-folder-to-a-page-at-root-level), I've also got problems with file paths that contain spaces.  I was told to simply enclose the full path in quotes, and that should work, but I keep getting this page marked up in my Webmaster Tools error log as not being found:

```
redirect 301 /"News/Press Releases/Press_Release_Update_Oct_2006.pdf" /index.html
```

still gives me a 404.

Thanks Martin

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried putting the quote before the /?

```
redirect 301 "/News/Press Releases/Press_Release_Update_Oct_2006.pdf" /index.html
```

Comment: No, I hadn't as I assumed the / at the start was not part of the path - that worked perfectly - thanks.  Merry Christmas :)