# Issue with redirection of a folder with mod_alias

Tags: .htaccess, directory, http-status-code-301, mod-alias

Another question following on from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776942/trouble-redirecting-all-pages-in-a-folder-to-a-page-at-root-level).  The only remaining item that I can't solve is that there is a listing for an now non-existent folder '/team/', but if I add this into my .htaccess file, it breaks all other .htaccess entries for files in that folder, i.e.

```
redirect 301 /team/ /team.html
redirect 301 /team/joe_bloggs.htm /team.html
redirect 301 /team/joe_bloggs.html /team.html
redirect 301 /team/bill_smith.htm /team.html
redirect 301 /team/bill_smith.html /team.html
```

If I then attempt to visit /team/joe_bloggs.htm, it takes me to

```
/team.html/joe_bloggs.htm
```

If I can fix this, it may help me understand how to resolve my original question and reduce the huge listing of redirect pages in my .htaccess file, so any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order, and put "`redirect 301 /team/ /team.html`" at the end.
It reads line to line and if it finds something fits, it replaces it.

Furthermore, I think you need to learn to add, ^ and $ characters. ^ means, the expression should begin, and $ means the expression should end.
So, `^/team/$` means, it should be exactly /team/ and it wont match `/team/joe_bloggs.htm`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and tip.  I'll implement them straight away.<br>
Cheers, and a happy new year to you<br>
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The [`Redirect` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) works on path prefixes. And in this case the path prefix used in your first directive (`/team/`) matches and the rest of the path is appended to the new URL path.

> […] any request beginning with *`URL-Path`* will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target *`URL`*. Additional path information beyond the matched *`URL-Path`* will be appended to the target *`URL`*.

Try [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/team/ /team.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.<br>
Cheers, and a happy new year to you<br>
Martin